# else if not working in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I have created a function in which I have taken if and else-if ladder when first two condition false it gets turn to third condition. Third condition contains two dates and one categoryid but query shows blank answer.

My function is:

```
public function getfeestransonedate() 
{  
    $odate=array_key_exists('odate',$_GET) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET["odate"])) : null;
    $sdate=array_key_exists('sdate',$_GET) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET["sdate"])) : null;
    $edate=array_key_exists('edate',$_GET) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET["edate"])) : null;
    $pdate=array_key_exists('pdate',$_GET) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET["pdate"])) : null;
    $qdate=array_key_exists('qdate',$_GET) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET["qdate"])) : null;            
    $categoryid=array_key_exists('categoryid',$_GET) ? : null;    
    //echo $categoryid; die;      

    try {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->SELECT('#__expense_transaction.expense_category_id, #__expense_transaction.date, #__expense_transaction.ammount as tamount, #__expense_transaction.transaction_details, #__expense_transaction.id, #__expenses_category_master.category_name');
        $query->FROM('#__expense_transaction, #__expenses_category_master');
        //var_dump(array($sdate,$edate,$odate));

        if($sdate && $edate) {
            $query->where('#__expense_transaction.date BETWEEN "'.$sdate.'" AND "'.$edate.'" AND #__expenses_category_master.id = #__expense_transaction.expense_category_id');
            // echo $query; die;
        } elseif($odate) {
            $query->where('#__expense_transaction.date = "'.$odate.'" AND #__expenses_category_master.id = #__expense_transaction.expense_category_id');
            //echo $query; die;
        }
        elseif($pdate && $qdate) {
            $query->where('#__expense_transaction.date BETWEEN "'.$pdate.'" AND "'.$qdate.'" AND #__expense_transaction.expense_category_id = "'.$categoryid.'" AND #__expenses_category_master.id = #__expense_transaction.expense_category_id');
            //echo $query; die;
        } else {
            echo 'Swapnil';
        }           
        // echo $query; die;    

        $db->setQuery((string)$query);                       
        $this->feestrans_data = $db->loadObjectList();

        if ($error = $db->getErrorMsg()) {
            throw new Exception($error);
        }
    }
    catch (JException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 404) {
            // Need to go thru the error handler to allow Redirect to work.
            JError::raiseError(404, $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Tell me if my query for third condition is right or wrong.

Comment: you need to `echo $odate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET["odate"]));` what it's output (1970-01-01)it's always gives you some output so need extra check in if

Comment: What i have to check?

Comment: Are you saying you are surprised that if the `if` is true, and the `if` block executes, that the `elseif` part doesn't get evaluated ???

Answer (score -1):

### **First note (and completely wrong):**

*Try writing `elseif(condition)` not `else if(condition)`.
More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php*

### **Second note (and this is your actual issue):**

You first need to check if $_GET[key] exists and only then convert it to date value. Otherwise it'll return PHPs default date value (1970-01-01) not `null` of `false` as you probably expected.

So You should do like this:

```
$odate=array_key_exists('odate',$_GET) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET["odate"])) : null;
$sdate=array_key_exists('sdate',$_GET) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET["sdate"])) : null;
$edate=array_key_exists('edate',$_GET) ? date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_GET["edate"])) : null;
```

Comment: i used that but still it not execute second condition

Comment: OK then add `var_dump(array($sdate,$edate,$odate));` before `if($sdate && $edate)` line and see what it returns.

Comment: OK, I understood your problem at last. Check updated answer above.

Comment: `elseif` and `else if` makes no difference. should try reading your own link: `In PHP, you can also write 'else if' (in two words) and the behavior would be identical to the one of 'elseif' (in a single word)`

Comment: it returns array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "1970-01-01" [1]=> string(10) "1970-01-01" [2]=> string(10) "2014-06-04" }

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 "thanks" for your downvote, but you're wrong. `else if` and `elseif` is not the same. In particular example see when `else {echo "Swapnil"}` will be executed in both cases.

Comment: see my second note above - that's your problem. Default date values 1970-01-01 are set if you pass null to date(). Also see how else if and elseif differ.

Comment: sorry you are wrong... `elseif` and `else if` are IDENTICAL funcationality when using curly brackets... only when using the older style `:` `endif;` method they are different. get a grip kid.

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 sorry, you're right about `else if` and `elseif` so your downvote is more than correct. I guess I have stepped out of my bed with wrong leg this morning :) I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you darkside your answer is right. It works for me. I have updated my question please help me

Comment: 1. Please accept my answer if it's correct. 2. Please don't change meaning of your question. You can only append more info, not change everything :) 3. You have something missing in this line `$categoryid=array_key_exists('categoryid',$_GET) ? *what do we have here? nothing :)* : null;`